# jQuery JavaScript

Tags: jquery

How can I write this code:

```
$(function()
{ 
$('#datetime').datepicker({duration: '',showTime: true,constrainInput: false});
});
```

in JavaScript `onclick`?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
$('#datetime').datepicker({duration: '',showTime: true,constrainInput: false});
})
```

Comment: Awesome; you beat me to it by 5 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#youdbuttonid").bind("click", function(){
      $('#datetime').datepicker({duration: '',showTime: true,constrainInput: false});
});
```